# Eclipse is extremely slow on Fedora 24

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am running a Fedora 24 OS (with GNOME 3) and I just installed the eclipse CDT package from the Fedora repositories (Eclipse CDT Neon.1), and it turned out to be extremely slow, but **only** when writing code or scrolling, the rest of the UI works perfectly and really quickly.

I have done some research about the topic and seemingly this problem is usually related to the GTK backend, and is commonly solved by running eclipse under GTK2 instead of GTK3. However, this has not helped me at all. The options I have tried are:

> export SWT_GTK3=0

And

> eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2 (also tried in eclipse.ini)

These two options effectively switch to GTK2, which is noticeable because the graphical appearance changes.

I tried also older versions of Eclipse (Juno, Kepler and Luna) and the problem still exists, probably even worse. I have increased the memory size for the JVM to 3GB and the problem remains intact.

The underlying hardware is a 6 core Intel Xeon (12 virtual cores with Hyperthreading) and 32 GB of RAM, so I assume this should not represent a problem.

I also noticed that while scrolling or writing, one of my cores goes to 70%-100% utilization, which explains the lag, but I don't know how to solve.

Is there any other option I can try?

Comment: You could try using a tool like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to take a profile during scrolling or typing. Feel free to [file a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with a profile attached.